# Multithreading or observer pattern when waiting for dns lookup?

Tags: java, multithreading, dns, observer-pattern

I'm designing a system in java which utilizes a dns lookup class.

My question is, when calling the class's dnsLookup(), whether to do it in a new thread or use the observer pattern and let the dns class tell me when it's done.

This isn't a problem as long as the lookup returns a value almost instantly but when it takes a few seconds (when it doesn't get a response), I don't want to freeze the GUI while waiting.

So, new thread or observer. Appreciate some good links on the subjects as well.

Thanks beforehand - Dennis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to employ both the observer pattern and more than one thread. There's no way to have the DNS invoking callback method in the same thread.

Comment: +1. We have an app doing quite a lot of DNS lookups, especially at startup. We use the observer pattern and let a thread pool handle the lookups.

Answer (score 0):

Your GUI is an event driver system so asynchronous notifications are good.

On the other hand, it's a lot easier to do network I/O (particularly if it's just a single DNS lookup) if you use  synchronous (blocking) network calls.

Hence I would tend to go for the separate thread option, but then have that thread notify the main GUI thread when it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a GUI that is making the call, I think it's best that you off-load the call to a different string. In fact, you want to make sure that you're not using the AWT-Thread to make a call that is blocking the GUI from refreshing. I would suggest using something like an [ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to execute your commands and then upon the return, use [SwingUtilities](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) and call the `invokeLater(Runnable doRun)` method to update the GUI with the response.